# "The connection id is in the incorrect format" in case of sso issued token based sites

Tags: signalr

I have read many other questions and [Github Issue](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1998) about this. The solution seems to be either call stop on the client before logging off or add the ping so that client doesn't get logged off automatcally.

> "The connection ID is in the incorrect format" or "The user identity
>   cannot change during an active SignalR connection" error
>
> This error may be seen if authentication is being used, and the client
>   is logged out before the connection is stopped. The solution is to
>   stop the SignalR connection before logging the client out.

However, in another typical scenario where only one person is allowed to be logged in to the site at one time, how should this be taken care of? I am talking about token based auth via sso where if the user logs on from another machine or browser and the auth token is invalidated for the previous session. In this case if the user gets to the previous session by doing anything the page refresh causes the user to be sent to login page (because the server knows that the auth token is invalid). However, if the user doesn't do anything on the previous page (it is open in background), the SignalR hosting app continues to throw the above mentioned error. How should this be dealt with? The host app throws tons of exceptions when this happens. Here is the stack trace...

```
Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.GetConnectionId(HostContext context, String connectionToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.CallHandler.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.Handlers.HubDispatcherHandler.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Utils.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetRethrowWithNoStackLossDelegate>b__0(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallContextAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add your report to SignalR issue https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2544

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is an issue in SignalR. It most likely is that I don't know how to do it. That is why I asked the question here rater than reporting an issue in Github.